# Aircraft fuselages being shipped on a boat

Tags: airplane, aircraft-disposal

Earlier this morning, my wife and I were down by the docks in Southampton (UK), watching cruise-liners move about with our binoculars. Whilst panning around, we noticed two old aircraft bodies (/fuselages - are the terms interchangeable?) on a large trailer, looking like they were waiting to be loaded onto a cargo vessel.

They had the wings, tail & nose removed, but the cavities that this exposes had been covered by yellow maintenance covers. I can't imagine they are simply being scrapped if the innards were protected like this.

So, I imagine they are being shipped somewhere for spares, is this trade a regular thing, and we just don't normally see it?

Comment: They looked bloody ancient. Very tatty, old-fashioned paintwork. One of them had the number Z733UK. I don't know where I'd look that up.

Comment: The Southern Daily Echo posted some [footage](https://www.dailyecho.co.uk/news/18485838.lorry-blocks-southampton-road/) of one of these holding up the traffic a few days ago. Unfortunately, the clip stops before I could get a clear view of the aircraft, but somebody might recognise the livery. I imagine the aircraft had been scrapped, but somebody, somewhere found a use for the fuselages intact.

Comment: Nice footage, thanks!

Comment: I added a screenshot from the video. In the comments of the video there was mention of the wings and tail also being transported.

Comment: The shipper https://www.finnieheavyhaulage.com/ doesn't seem to think it's noteworthy.  Their webpage gallery and facebook page brag about other unusual loads, but not (yet) this one.

Comment: Can I just make a quick comment about this post and everything about it? I have tried to engage with a few Stack Exchange forums at various times throughout the last decade or so. In every case, within the first week, someone would inevitably either find something objectionable about a question, comment, or answer I posted, or they would lambaste me in a comment and point out 45 -50 ways I had failed to comply with their set of ridgid requirements. I'm not sure where that culture sprung from, but it turned be off every time. And then this post, no question, just coolness, and no insults! 

Comment: Just a quick note. I've rolled back everyone's over-enthusiastic edits. The question was about these things being spotted by a quayside, not about them being hauled via trailer. Admittedly, the one leads to the other, but the title edit completely changed my question.

Comment: @Bignutz. Apart from the fact that the question was changed by (I'm sure) well-meaning folks, and I got an answer to a different question.

Comment: (I asked that initial question because an unpainted fuselage may look derelict while it is in fact brand new. Deleted the comment now that it's obvious it concerns a used fuselage)

Comment: @Sanchises. Thanks, that's no problem. It was the editing it into a different question I objected to.

Comment: You should transform the title in more precise question (this is a Q&A website) to ease navigation without opening each question. There may be other questions about transportation of aircraft parts by boat.

Comment: @ManuH Are there, though?

Comment: @SiHa not yet, but think about making your question future-proof.. and following the same conventions as other question on aviation.SE

Comment: Road and boat transport are usually 2 stages of the same journey.  Roads go everywhere, but have width and height limits that make transporting outsize items like aircraft difficult, disruptive and expensive. Boat transport has fewer size limits but canals don't go everywhere. So the usual route is start site->road->nearest accessible waterway->road->finish.

Answer (score 4):

The aircraft you saw was N733UK (not Z733UK). It's a Boeing 737-300, most recently operated by European Aviation Group, and before that by easyJet  and bmibaby. It was stored at Bournemouth Airport in 2015 and subsequently dismantled.

This site suggests it's on its way to China to be used for training.

https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/boeing-737-300-n733uk-european-aviation-group/rovlz3

Answer (score 3):

Road and boat transport of airliners is difficult and expensive. If possible, the last flight of an aircraft will end at a place where it can be dismantled.

Nevertheless, not all aircraft end up as scrap. Some have their final destination in a museum, or have a second live as a hotel, or restaurant, or some sort of decoration. These places can be far away from an airport and require transport over water and/or streets.

Retired aircraft are usually sold at auctions, and anybody may buy a 747 
for their back yard (if it fits).

Next time you witness a transport like this, try to spot the registration number. If you have that number, it is very easy to look up the history and - possibly - the destination of that aircraft.

Examples:

- Concorde [F-BVFB](https://www.heritageconcorde.com/f-bvfb-207) travelling to the Technik Museum in Sinsheim (Germany):

  [image]

  <sup>Image source: [Technik-Museum Sinsheim](https://sinsheim.technik-museum.de/nl/concorde)</sup>
- Boeing 747 [PH-BFB](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH-BFB) became a decoration for a hotel. It didn't have to travel far from Amsterdam airport, but it had to be pulled across a highway in the night.

  [image]

  <sup>Image source: [Hart van Nederland](https://www.hartvannederland.nl/nieuws/2019/boeing-747-eindelijk-op-zijn-plek-bij-hotel-in-badhoevedorp/#1145020)</sup>

Comment: Not to mention multimode transportation (e.g. for the [A380](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/how-is-an-aircraft-built/transport-of-major-aircraft-sections.html))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, you answered a different question to the one I posted. Not your fault.

Comment: @siha  Hmm, could you please clarify what actually is your question?

Comment: Of course. I was simply asking if aircraft bodies are routinely shipped via boat, because it seems expensive, and not something I'd ever witnessed despite living at a major international port for over 30 years. Alas, someone saw fit to add a picture of it being shipped by road, and then someone edited the title (and the text, IIRC) and it became a different question. Which you answered. I'm aware that boat/sea is a subtle distinction, but I didn't ask about road shipment.

Comment: @SiHa I'm a sailor, 'on a boat' vs 'on the sea' doesn't sound like a subtle difference to me. These are two entirely different meanings. I was not aware of the discussion that developed under your question in the past 24h. I think my answer should be valid even for your original question: it is not something done routinely.